# How to call a method on a Vue.js component when a particular value is populated, but only once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm working on an application that uses Vue.js (currently v 2.6.11), and as the application grows I see a pattern emerge quite often: I want to abstract away some functionality, so I extract a new component, but when I copy some code in the `mounted` hook from the parent to the child, some of the data that were previously available are now undefined. Sometimes the data comes from a prop, other times it comes from a Vuex store.

I think the issue comes from the fact that, contrarily to what I initially thought, inner components are initialized before outer components.

Here is an example:

#### Parent component

```html
<template>
    <div class="options-container">
        <features-list />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import FeaturesList from '../features/FeaturesList.vue';

export default {
    name: 'ProductComponent',
    components: {
        FeaturesList,
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('product', [
            'userSelection',
        ]),
    },
    mounted() {
        // here I can call the methods which rely on UserSelections
        // the variable UserSelections has already a value here
        const params = this.getTemplateCollectionParams();
        this.getTemplateAssets(params);
    },
};
</script>
```

#### Child component

```html
<template>
    <div class="options">
        <template v-for="key in sortedFeaturesLayout">
            <feature-base-component
                :option="options[key]"
                :key="key"
                v-on="$listeners"
            />
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import FeatureBaseComponent from './FeatureBaseComponent.vue';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'FeaturesList',
    components: {
        FeatureBaseComponent,
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('product', [
            'userSelection',
        ]),
    },
    methods: {
        getTemplateCollectionParams() {
            // ...
        },
        getTemplateAssets(params) {
            // ...
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        // here I have an error because `userSelection` is still empty
        const params = this.getTemplateCollectionParams();
        this.getTemplateAssets(params);
    },
};
</script>
```

What I usually do is create a watcher on the value and then call the function on the update of the watcher. Since the original code was executing only once I want to check that this method is called only once too, so add a boolean that checks if this code has already been executed.

```html
<template>
    <div class="options">
        <template v-for="key in sortedFeaturesLayout">
            <feature-base-component
                :option="options[key]"
                :key="key"
                v-on="$listeners"
            />
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import FeatureBaseComponent from './FeatureBaseComponent.vue';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'FeaturesList',
    components: {
        FeatureBaseComponent,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isFirstLoad: true,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('product', [
            'userSelection',
        ]),
    },
    methods: {
        getTemplateCollectionParams() {
            // ...
        },
        getTemplateAssets(params) {
            // ...
        },
    },
    watch: {
        userSelection() {
            // get gallery
            if (this.isFirstLoad) {
                // here I need the getter userSelection which is empty on `mounted`
                const params = this.getTemplateCollectionParams();
                this.getTemplateAssets(params);
                this.isFirstLoad = false;
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

I think that what I'm doing is not completely wrong. However, I wonder if there is a cleaner way of executing a method only the first time a prop has a value because sometimes I end up with plenty of booleans, which are only used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively use [`vm.$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch), which returns an `unwatch` function that can be called to stop subsequent callbacks:

```js
const unwatch = this.$watch('userSelection', userSelection => {
  //...

  // stop watching
  unwatch()
})
```

This has the benefits of not requiring an extra flag to check whether the watch handler has already been called, and the watcher is only ever called once.

[image: Edit Unwatching a value in Vue]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed! I had seen something similar in other examples, but didn't think I could call `unwatch` directly in the callback function